# Oozie Error E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, User: vidya.pandey is not allowed to impersonate vidya.pandey

Tags: impersonation, oozie

I am trying to run Oozie in my localhost for learning. Oozie server is up and running fine.
    But when I try to execute the example job , it gives be below error:-

```
Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, User: vidya.pandey is not allowed to impersonate vidya.pandey

....
```

My user name is vidya.pandey and oozie software is installed with same name.

I followed the suggestions on web and tried many combinations to solve above error. but I failed. Please help me how to solve this error.

Please suggest how to put my user name "vidya.pandey" in oozie-site.xml

oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.#USER#.hosts

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your current user in the HDFS core-site as proxyuser. Add the following configuration in the `HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.current_user.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.current_user.hosts</name>
  <value>host_name_server_running</value>
</property>
```

In the above replace `current_user` with the desired user name value and replace `host_name_server_running` with the name of your server.

Essentially, the user who is running the oozie server process should be added as the proxy user in the `core-site.xml`. In your case, it happens to be the same user.

Comment: Hello Hobbit , Thanks for replying , But I already tried that. My current user is "vidya.pandey". So please suggest me how to add that user name where there is dot "." in user name. <property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.vidya\.pandey.hosts</name>
  <value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.vidya\.pandey.groups</name>
  <value>vidya.pandey</value>
</property>